# Why My App Checks @property Declaration Instead of @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4

I'm debugging my code because it crashes, and has one rare behavior, or I guess that. When has to check one variable declaration, the debug goes to check it to its @property declaration, instead @synthesize. What can be the reason of that? Can it be the reason why my app crashed?
UPDATE:
Here is the link of my project, because it is kind of big, and put just a little code IT wasn't going to be enough, I think
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/63305852/GRP_5.1.zip

Comment: Not sure what the question is. What you mean by " check one variable declaration"?

Comment: When you declare one variable in Objective-C, you declare it in Header file, in this way: property..., and then you declare it in your Implementation file, in this way: synthesize.... When the compiler checks your variable, goes to the synthesize in the Implementation file, and that always happen to me. But now that enable ARC in my project, and this change some retain to strong, and assign to weak, the compiler checks the variable in property instead of synthesize, and I think this can be the reason why my app crashes

Comment: synthesize creates your instance variable and your setter and getter. property does not. Can you post the crash log?

Comment: Now that check all my code in debug mode, always check property instead synthesize. and this starts when change my project to ARC

Comment: I already put the link to my project, because is kind of big. I update the project again, and still have that error. When I update, and I'm debugging, the debug checks my variables property instead synthesize. Do I need to chance one parameter in Build Settings when I update?.. I'll really appreciate the help, so If you have any question about my project, you can always ask, or some suggestion...

Comment: The error is when I update from 4.3 to 5.1